# Irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{C} [x,y ]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> I want to prove that $t^4+xt^3+yt^2+xt+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

I know that $\mathbb{C}[x,y][t]$ is a UFD just as $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ because the base ring is a field. Can I just change the order of the indeterminates and use $x$ as indeterminate to show that it is irreducible?

Comment: WHat do you mean by «Can I just change the order of the indeterminates?»?

Comment: Notice your polynomial is linear in $y$. If $f\cdot g$ is a factorization, one of the factors must be of degree zero with respect to $y$, that is, independent of $y$, and if $f$ is this factor, it has to divide $t^2$ and $t^4+xt^3+xt+1$ in $C[x,t]$.

Comment: I follow the first part, and that's what I meant with changing the order, seeing it as a polynomial in $y$, yet I don't see why it follows that $f$ has to divide those two polynomials.

Comment: the other factor, $g$, must be of the form $ay+b$ with $a$ and $b$ in $C[x,t]$, and the product $fg$ must equal your original polynomial.